# bootstrap horizontal menu with mouse over horizontal submenu with gab

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to webpage display menu with sub menus mouse over display horizontal and keep gap and click(without change main menu position). I have developed, it is not working correctly. I have added all details with screen.

This is my cshtml code.

```html
<div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="active dropdown-toggle"><a role="tab" href="#one" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
            <li><a role="tab" href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
            <li><a role="tab" href="#three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown" id="mysubmenu">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Testing</a>
                <nav class="navbar" id="mysubmenu" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                           <li><a href="#">Test sub 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Test sub 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Test sub 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Test sub 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

This is my jQuery class

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
       $("#mysubmenu ul").hide();

        $("#mysubmenu a").mouseover(function () {
            var isdropdown = $("#mysubmenu").hasClass("dropdown");
            //alert(isdropdown);
            if (isdropdown) {
                $("#mysubmenu ul").show();

                $("#mysubmenu").removeClass("dropdown");
                $("#mysubmenu").addClass("dropup");
            } else {
                $("#mysubmenu ul").hide();
                $("#mysubmenu").removeClass("dropup");
                $("#mysubmenu").addClass("dropdown");
            }

            event.preventDefault();
        });

      

    })
    </script>
```

This is my CCS

```css
.nav-tabs> li.active > a, .nav-tabs> li.active > a:hover, .submenu > .nav {
    
}
```

This is my out put with details and final out put
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add padding top to "#mysubmenu ul"

```
#mysubmenu ul
  {
    padding-top:100px;
  }
```

Comment: still change position main menu and can't click sub menus

Comment: When I mouse over main menu (Testing) will change position main menu. How can I keep main menu fix place.